# Why does this error keep popping up? Missing { inserted. \end{split}

Tags: errors, split

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
G & =G$_x$+G$_y$ \\ 
& =E$_x$+$\frac{1}{2}$k$_B$T[xlnx+(1-x)ln(1-x)]\\ 
& + E$_y$ + k$_B$T[ylny+(1-y)ln(1-y)] \\ 
& =E$_x$+$\frac{1}{2}$k$_B$T[xlnx+(1-x)ln(1-x)]\\ 
& + E$_{\rm(c-x)}$+k$_B$T[(c-x)ln(c-x)+(1-c+x)ln(1-c+x)],
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Logs show that:

```
 Missing `{` inserted. `\end{split}` and missing `$` inserted `\end{split}`
```

Comment: Welcome! Please post complete code we can use to reproduce errors/problems when asking questions.

Comment: Down-voted with no explanation within half an hour of a first question, which includes both code and the text of the error message, by a two-day-old member of the site? What do you want? Blood?

Comment: @cfr, it was not me downvoting.

Comment: @Sigur I didn't think it was ;).

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `$` inside another math environment, like `equation` for example. To have a single numbered block of equations aligned on equal sign, use `aligned` inside `equation` (observe the use of `\ln` and `\quad`):

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
G &=G_x+G_y \\ 
  &=E_x+\frac{1}{2}k_BT[x\ln x+(1-x)\ln(1-x)]\\ 
  & \quad + E_y + k_BT[y\ln y+(1-y)\ln(1-y)] \\ 
  &=E_x+\frac{1}{2}k_BT[x\ln x+(1-x)\ln(1-x)]\\ 
  & \quad + E_{(c-x)}+k_BT[(c-x)\ln(c-x)+(1-c+x)\ln(1-c+x)],
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

[image]